# python library to fetch content(http text) from the websites?

Tags: python, url, python-2.7

I'd like something equivalent to `urlopen` from `urllib` python library to fetch data from the web,

`urlopen` does not seem to work on sites like google or youtube, probably due to incorrect headers,

So any other python based content fetcher i can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example with `urllib2` that fetches a web page:

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://google.com/')
html = response.read()
```

The example is taken from the [urllib2 documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html).